# Mariadb restore schema from .frm files

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have no ibdata1 or other files just the .frm ones and I only need the schema, if I copy them to mariadb/data/mydatabase and then try to access them from within my phpmyadmin it says table not found, if I first create tables with the same names and then replace them with the .frm files it only works for the first table and crashes for the rest.

Comment: please paste any error messages

Comment: There are no error messages. Except for when the table doesn't exist, says "database.tablename doesn't exist" exactly.